# Athena query fails with: "Insufficient permissions to execute the query"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I am writing a lambda function that is supposed to initiate a query against Athena, when I execute a start_query_execution it succeeds but when I later try to get the query status I see the following:

```
'Status': {'State': 'FAILED', 'StateChangeReason': 'Insufficient permissions to execute the query. User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/test_role/test-audit is not authorized to perform: glue:GetTable on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:catalog ', 'SubmissionDateTime': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 16, 17, 13, 18, 749000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'CompletionDateTime': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 16, 17, 13, 31, 197000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}
```

The lambda has the an IAM role assigned to it with the following permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "dynamodb:*",
            "kinesis:*",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "athena:*",
            "glue:*",
            "redshift:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

Based on the role I would think it could do anything it needs to with Athena against any S3 bucket in this account, but its failing. All the S3 resources are in the same account as the lambda where the code is executing, as well as the athena table. The start query is configured as following:

```
response = athena.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        ClientRequestToken=hashlib.md5(query.encode()).hexdigest(),
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'test'
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://athena-test.query.results/test/',
            'EncryptionConfiguration': {
                'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'
            }
        }
    )
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the name of the IAM role assumed by your function? Can you share the rest of the lambda code?

Comment: Is your S3 data in a bucket that uses encryption? If so you might need to grant kms GenerateDataKey permissions and allow access to relevant KMS keys so that it can decrypt data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong except stale behavior in the AWS console.

Comment: Wait really? I'm hitting this issue. All I need to do is wait?

Comment: Yep that’s all I did

Comment: Can confirm, waited a while and all started working. Kind of a pain in the butt and I don't really trust real-time automation workflows if there is unknown delays but you're right "just wait" is the answer :)

Comment: How long did you end up waiting? Seconds, minutes, ... ?

Comment: Hours, but it may have only needed minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the permission may help.

I tried like this

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "glue:GetTable"
  Resource:
    - "*"
```

inside resource you can specify bucket name also.